Looking for a novel about people becoming their totem animals
Read this novel some time in the nineties and haven't been able to find it again.
I remember is it was a paperback, and  it had a green cover.
This scientist goes to the Amazon jungle, where he observes the natives performing a ritual where they take a drug that temporarily turns them into their totem animal, like, half animal half human, for a few hours.
Then some unsavory business types discover this drug, take it back to Tampa, Florida, where they synthesize it and make it more potent. They start selling it in nightclubs as a recreational drug, but then something goes wrong. People turn into their totem animals but they can't turn back, so there are half wolf half human, half shark half human, etc., running around Tampa munching on each other.
It's up to the altruistic scientist to find a way to solve the problem and reverse the effect of the drug. And of course there's a love story in there to. Has anyone else read this book?
